# Node.js, Mongoose, MongoDB ECONREFUSED error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, econnrefused

I am working through Pluralsight's RESTful Web Services... tutorial, but am running into an error very early on.

The error is:

```
...\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:228

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at ICPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

This is the app.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookAPI');

var Book = require('./models/bookModel');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var bookRouter = express.Router();

bookRouter.route('/Books')
    .get(function(req, res){
        Book.find(function(err, books){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                res.json(books);
            }
        });
    });

app.use('/api', bookRouter);



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("Here");
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Gulp is running my app on PORT: " + port);
});
```

It runs fine if I comment out

`var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookAPI');`

Comment: Try out this "mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/bookAPI"

Comment: Is MongoDb installed and working properly ?